# Sorting in nsmutable array

Tags: objective-c, sorting, nsarray

Suppose I have following data in my game. I have developed game in cocos2d.

```
Name    Score
Sagar   10000
Amit     2000
Vishal     90
```

Above data is stored in plist file.

Plist has an array as root.

Within that there are 10 dictionary.

Each dictionary has two values:

- String values - Name
- Number value - score

When I use

```
NSMutableArray *x=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Sagar.plist"];
```

I want to sort this mutable array by score.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a sort descriptor:

```
NSSortDescriptor * sortByScore = [[[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"Score" ascending:NO] autorelease];
NSArray * descriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObject:sortByScore];
NSArray * sorted = [x sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:descriptors];
```

Answer (score 1):

See [`[NSMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingDescriptors:), [`[NSMutableArray sortUsingComparator:]`](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/sortUsingComparator:) and so on. NSMutableArray provides several methods for sorting. In this case, I'd use the descriptor method if I needed to be compatible before 10.5 and the comparator method for Snow Leopard apps.

Comment: My question is modified a little bit sir.

Answer (score 1):

I believe on the iPhone, your options are

```
- (void)sortUsingFunction:(NSInteger (*)(id, id, void *))compare context:(void *)context;
```

and

```
- (void)sortUsingSelector:(SEL)comparator;
```

there is a bunch of decent info on it here:
http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?SortUsingSelector

EDIT: whoops! saw cocos2d and assumed it was an iPhone question.

Comment: No, No. It is an iPhone question. I am using plist for score storing. Question is about plist & array with plist. No need to worry. I am studying your given link.