# Sorting an array in objective-c

Tags: objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [sorting in nsmutable array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1684157/sorting-in-nsmutable-array)

I have 2 NSMutableArray array. I have to sort it. Is there any function defined in Objective-c for direct sort.

like

NSMutableArray *sortedarray_variable= (sorting method) array_variable;

Where sorting method returns sorted array.

Comment: Here's a very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/805547/how-to-sort-an-nsmutablearray-with-custom-objects-in-it

Comment: Also, -1 for not searching. This is such a basic question that was answered dozens of times on SO and could easily be answered by reading the NSArray documentation.

Comment: I have to sort in ascending or descending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course. `NSArray` provides several [methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)